# How to make sure test framework is reliable and credible?

Tags: automated-testing

Test frameworks help in test automation. However, as any software, they can and they do contain bugs. Just to give examples:

- [TestNG issues](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues)
- REST-Assured [issues](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/issues/637) and [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rest-assured)

What metrics one should use to choose the framework that it credible and reliable?

Some I can think of:

- Test framework itself has high test/code coverage
- Reported bugs are fixed quickly
- Framework is used widely in the domain similar to the one I want to use it
- It is easy to fix some bugs on my own (the code is clear, authors accepts contributions and bug fixes)

What else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All useful software has bugs, and neither the length of the bug list nor the unit test code coverage will tell you whether a test framework meets your needs.

Where I work, groups use either JUnit or TestNG for Java unit testing.  We chose them because they are widely used, and so most of the common bugs -- the ones we are mostly likely to encounter -- have already been fixed.  Any common bugs that are not fixed are probably well-documented in release notes or in something like StackOverflow.

If I were selecting a unit-testing framework from scratch, I would consider the following:

- Is it open-source? (binary metric)
- Is the documentation adequate?
- Are there lots of examples written by people other than the authors?
- Is it easy to get answers to questions, preferably because someone else already asked them and answered them.
- When people answer questions about the framework, do they tend to sound satisfied with it, or do they sound angry/frustrated?

The question specifically asked for metrics, and most of those points are not phrased quantitatively, but I think you could find ways to quantify most of them.

**Edit**

The Op specifically wants to know whether test/code coverage will tell them anything about test framework reliability.  I would be concerned about a framework with no unit tests, but if I were comparing two frameworks that both had unit tests, I would be reluctant to choose one over the other based solely on which one had more test/code coverage.

Comment: Do you mean the test/code coverage will not tell me anything about test framework reliability? That was the question.

Comment: @dzieciou Sorry, I misunderstood.  I thought the question was, "What metrics one should use to choose the framework that it credible and reliable?"

Comment: you're right, that was the question. But don't you agree that test/code coverage is one of those metrics?